# Gnome shell network manager notification missing icon

Tags: 11.10, gnome, icons, notify-osd

I am using ubuntu 11.10 + gnome shell, and when I disconnect from a network the notification icon is missing, here is a screenshot:

[image]

Does someone knows where can I find which icon the notification is trying to use so I can add it to the current icons theme?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 2):

At least for Ubuntu 12.04, the broken icon results from network-manager-gnome requesting an icon named `notification-network-disconnected` when disconnecting from a network, which is missing. In case of a wired network network-manager-gnome would prefer `notification-network-ethernet-disconnected` and in case of a wireless `notification-network-wireless-disconnected` (`network-manager-applet-0.9.4.1/src/applet.c` from the line 2396 on).

An easy workaround when using the GNOME icon theme would be to symlink each occurrence of `nm-no-connection.png` to `notification-network-{,ethernet-,wireless-}disconnected.png`. Then rebuild the icon cache for `/usr/share/icons/gnome/`, e.g.:

```
export iconTheme=/usr/share/icons/gnome

for px in 16 22 24 32 48 256 ; do sudo ln -s ${iconTheme}/${px}x${px}/status/nm-no-connection.png ${iconTheme}/${px}x${px}/status/notification-network-disconnected.png ; done

for px in 16 22 24 32 48 256 ; do sudo ln -s ${iconTheme}/${px}x${px}/status/nm-no-connection.png ${iconTheme}/${px}x${px}/status/notification-network-ethernet-disconnected.png ; done

for px in 16 22 24 32 48 256 ; do sudo ln -s ${iconTheme}/${px}x${px}/status/nm-no-connection.png ${iconTheme}/${px}x${px}/status/notification-network-wireless-disconnected.png ; done

sudo update-icon-caches ${iconTheme}
```

Please note that these commands fix only the GNOME icon theme, but you can easily modify them to fit your favourite theme if it provides suitable icons.